# replace the value of specific index in multidimensional nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays which look like this

Array1

```
[
    "008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59" => [
        "2707bd40-d421-400d-ba55-694632facadd" => [],
        "307e97e0-be81-4644-b842-dcd23e88d09f" => []
    ],
    "86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51" => []
]
```

Array2

```
[
    "c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0" => [
        "008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59" => [],
        "86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51" => []
    ],
    "651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078" => [],
    "eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748" => []
]
```

Array 2 is the parent array, i.e. somewhere at any index the whole Array1 is part of Array2.
I want to replace Values of indexes in Array2 that are equal to Array1 indexes such as:

```
008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59
```

And

```
86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51
```

respectively.

The output should be one final Array that looks like this

```
[   
    "c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0" => [
        "008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59" => [
            "2707bd40-d421-400d-ba55-694632facadd" => [],
            "307e97e0-be81-4644-b842-dcd23e88d09f" => []
        ],
        "86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51" => []
    ],
    "651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078" => [],
    "eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748" => []
]
```

I tried using this through

```
array_replace()

array_replace_recursive()

foreach() loop
```

but all in vain, cuz tricky part is the child array can exist anywhere e.g. within array or within array or n arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursion. Then you will meet every key in array2 and check whether it matches with a key in array1. When there is a match, just replace the value for that key. I assume that the keys are overall unique.

Here is a function you could use:

```
function extend($array2, $array1) {
    if (!is_array($array2)) return $array2;
    foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $array2[$key] = isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : extend($value, $array1);
    }
    return $array2;
}
```

For your example, call it like this:

```
$array1 = [
    "008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59" => [
        "2707bd40-d421-400d-ba55-694632facadd" => [],
        "307e97e0-be81-4644-b842-dcd23e88d09f" => []
    ],
    "86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51" => []
];
    
$array2 = [
    "c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0" => [
        "008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59" => [],
        "86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51" => []
    ],
    "651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078" => [],
    "eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748" => []
];

$result = extend($array2, $array1);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array first and after that, you only need to look by key in the flatten array.

```
    function array_flatten($array) {
        $return = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $return[$key] = $value;
            if (is_array($value)){
                $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));
            }
        }
    
        return $return;
    }
    
    function get_hidratated_array($toHidratate, $master) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($toHidratate as $key=>$value ){
            if(isset($master[$key])) {
                $result[$key] = $master[$key];
            } else {
                $result[$key] = hidratate_array($value, $master);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    
    $flat = array_flatten($array1);
    $result = get_hidratated_array($array2, $flat);
    print_r($result);
```